# is it possible to set interval time between Jobs in NodeJS using npm Queue/P-limit in order to run only one job each second?

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue

is it possible to set interval time between Jobs in NodeJS using npm Queue/P-limit in order to run only one job each second? I've been searching for a solution but have not found any
Thanks

Comment: Check if [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) helps you

Comment: If it's a matter of executing some code each second, then you might not even need any package, [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) might do just fine.

Comment: thank you, guys! I found a solution which is p-queue. It allows us to control the concurrency & set interval time between jobs at the same time